# Proper jQuery chaining

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to chain this piece of code:

```
$('.testslides :first-child').fadeOut();
$('.restslides :last-child').prependTo('.slides').fadeIn();
```

into this:

```
$('.testslides :first-child').fadeOut().find('.slide last-child').prependTo('.slides').fadeIn();
```

but it doesn't work. where am I doing it wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You can't. Because I assume there is no `.slide :last-child` as children of `.slides :first-child`

Comment: Why would it work? You're using `find()` from the child element to find a sibling of the first element. You've also changed the second selector.

Comment: Yes but when I use end() to reverse back to .slides it doesn't work too.

Comment: @pershianix Giving the HTML would be best of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was *`$('.slides :first-child')`* will get all the children elements, which is a `first-child` of any of the inner html elements.

So use **[`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)** then **[`.eq(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** to get the children and take the first one from them. As an alternative CSS selector **`$('.slides > :first-child')`**.

[`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) is used to find the children of an element. Use either

1. [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) then [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)
2. [`closest('.slides')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) then [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)
3. [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

and get the [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) item.

```
$('.slides').children().eq(0).fadeOut()
     .siblings().last().prependTo('.slides').fadeIn();
```

Comment: You can also use ``.first()`` instead of ``.eq(0)``.

Comment: @seahorsepip yes. definitely.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first) and [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last) combining [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end) method:

```
$('.slides').first().fadeOut().end().last().prependTo('.slides').fadeIn();
```

Comment: Thank you but your solution isn't working. It's fading out the whole div (.slides) and not the first child.

Comment: It's fading out the whole div (.slides) and not the first child.

Comment: @pershianix Check the first part of my answer. :)